# Apache Proxy Server timeout isn't working as expected

Tags: apache, proxy, server, weblogic

Apache proxy Server timeout isn't working as expected.

Apache Server V 2.4

My apache proxy server config is something like this.

```
<Config>
<VirtualHost someurl.com:8003>
ServerName someurl.com:8003

<Location "/">
ProxyPass "https://www.someotherurl.com/"  timeout=300 keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse "https://www.someotherurl.com/" 
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I used a standalone tool to calculate the time elapsed for connection establishment and found out that the connection is timing out in 21secs,Eventhough the specified timeout is 300s

Code:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://someurl.com:8003/',verify=False)
print response.elapsed
print response.raise_for_status()
print response.status
```

Why isn't the timeout working properly ? The expected behavior is connection timeout happening after 300s right ?? Any other config changes are required ?

PS: I have a weblogic server hitting this apache proxy server and weblogic server will timeout in 90s.The Idea is ,weblogic server  to timeout before apache proxy server does.  Any kind of help is appreciated :)